# Qt Libraries are not included

Tags: c++, qt, include

I checked if the question exists but it doesn't seem to help me. I'm clearly new to Qt, i installed Qt Creator 5.4 in my Windows 7 Ultimate. I installed everything Qt 5.4 provides and also installed MinGW 4.9.1. The problem is when i open a console application project it immediately gives these errors. I tried different projects and error is the same.

```
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: core
```

I tried to check intellisense for include and it didn't show **ANY** library to me.

When i hover to include it gives : `QCoreApplication: No such file or directory`

I highly doubt Qt can't find it's own libraries. How can i show it to QtCreator ?

Additional info : Run button and everything related to run is disabled.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: What kit is in use?  Have you looked in `Qt Creator > Tools >  Options > Build & Run`  There are two tabs to look at to make sure they don't have errors next to them: Kits, and Qt Versions.  If you installed Qt Creator separately from the Qt Libraries you may have this issue, where you need to manually set up the paths.

Comment: Yeah there are errors. These ones with errors are MSVC2012 and MSVC2013. I think it's related to Visual studio. I realised now i need to add paths manually but how ?

Comment: The easiest way, is to close all the Qt Creator things, and rename the current Qt folder to Qt_old, and re download it and install it with Qt Creator and the Qt Libraries and MingW at the same time, but it takes a while.  Reading the tool tip text for each error and finding the path to the correct folder with `qmake.exe` or the `g++.exe` or whatever is doable but takes more work.  You may need to add a kit for MingW, and make sure all the fields are filled in properly.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-targets.html

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-qmake.html

Comment: Unfortunately i have already re-installed three times. Second time i have added every tool, it installed 16+ gigabytes but still nothing changed. Under the Qt Versions it has "No qmlscene installed" error.

Comment: what is on your path right now?  Is it finding qmake.exe in the wrong folder because of the system or user path?

Comment: No it finds true path for qmake.exe
Edit : I fixed mingw kit but i can't change qt versions because it automatically added itself with true path.

Comment: Post some screenshots of what you are seeing in your Build & Run tabs.  That should show more of what is going on.  And read those two links I posted above...  I'm running Qt 5.4 on Win 8.1 with MingW and MSVC on it, and Android armv7.... After you post those, maybe we should move some of this conversation to chat.

Comment: I already read and did them, don't worry :)

Comment: http://prntscr.com/77txhp - kits http://prntscr.com/77tynz -qt vrsions

Comment: what does it show when you click on the MingW ones... the extra info below?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/77u03p

Comment: Installing to Program Files is asking for trouble.  Program Files has a space in the name, and only some of the tools support having a space in the path to the bin folder.

Comment: Let it install to `C:/Qt/` and you should be golden.

Comment: Or to `C:/tools/Qt/`

Comment: I'm going to try it. Thanks for help. Maybe that's the reason it doesn't see any library. I'm going to feedback when i'm done :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your project's path contains non ASCII characters.
Try a new project somewhere like C:\MyApp

Comment: This is not connected to the problem but i've tried it, still no help.